# readxl does not import all rows of the excel file

Tags: r, excel, readxl

When importig my excel file (159,156 rows, 25 columns) it imports as a smaller file.

```
library(readxl) 
All_wp <- read_excel("~/path/file.xls")
```

generates a file with 65535 obs (rows) and 25 variables.

Why is this?
is there a limit for file rowns on readxl? If so, what other package can I use to import bigger excel documents?

Comment: I don't think there's a limit... `read_excel` automatically removes the last rows if they are empty, maybe thats the case?

Comment: Its not the case at all, all the rows have numbers, some have zeros, but a minimum value of 1 or higher on each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the table and running

```
my_data <- read.table(pipe("pbpaste"), sep="\t", header = TRUE)
```

works!

Still, not sure if there is a row limit on readxl for importing excel files?